# Let ABC be a triangle such that AB = √2 BC = √3 and ∠ABC = 120°

Tags: triangles

Let ABC be a triangle such that AB = √2 BC = √3 and ∠ABC = 120°.

What is the length of line AC?

What is the area of triangle ABC?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this question? Do you know any rules relating angles and sides?

Comment: Please use the body of the Question to give the complete problem statement.  Splitting the setup and query between title and body invites confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** Cosine's Law is your friend here.